# SSIS Excel Source - Error with empty DT_NTEXT column

Tags: excel, ssis

We are currently facing an issue with Excel Source component. We have to read mutipples Excel files with same structure and insert their data into one SQL table.
We use ForEach container that read all the files in the specified folder (with variables) and transfer data to the SQL table. On the first file (whiwh was used for the Excel Source configuration), there is a column with more than 4000 chars (5036 exacly). Excel driver automatically identified it as DT_NTEXT (and it's ok) and the auto-created SQL table has NVARCHAR(MAX) as type.

On the fifth file, this column doesn't contains data at all. And when trying to transfer data, the package fails with the error below

> [Excel Source [14]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.
>
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft Access Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80040E21  Description: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.".
>
> [Excel Source [14]] Error: Failed to retrieve long data for column "Comment".
>
> [Excel Source [14]] Error: There was an error with Excel Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output] on Excel Source. The column status returned was: "DBSTATUS_UNAVAILABLE".
>
> [Excel Source [14]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Excel Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output]" failed because error code 0xC0209071 occurred, and the error row disposition on "Excel Source" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Excel Source returned error code 0xC0209029.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

I have made some search on the internet, no solution worked for me.

I tried:

- Add IMEX=1 at the end of the Excel ConnectionString
- Update the TypeGuessRows value on the registry key for the JET driver
- Changed output type on Advanced Editor
  and others solutions maybe, but I do not remember them all

Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Since the file has a different structure, it would need to be a new connection.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but precisely, the documents are created from the same model. 
The problem is that in one of the files, there is no data on a given column (and it's completely ok, in this type of records, this field remains empty). Does the absence of data in a file necessarily imply the creation of another template?
Tomorrow I don't know if in another column the data will be empty too. So the package will crash?
What I want is to make sure that the Excel source component "ignores" the presence or not of data on a column of type ntext.

Comment: If the column is completely empty, Excel will not identify it as a column.  If the number of columns is different, it would need to be a new connection.  You could try redirecting on error to another output path to load from a connection with fewer columns.